# how to add multiple field to same object

Tags: c#

**The question is how to dynamically add properties and values to a dynamically created object**

Previously asked

> I want to add multiple field to an object dynamically, i am using the
>   following code but with each loop it remove the previous and add the
>   latest, but i want the object to hold all values.
>
> ```
> SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
> var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, sdr.FieldCount).Select(sdr.GetName).ToList();
> if (sdr.HasRows)
> {
>     allRows = new ArrayList();
>     while (sdr.Read())
>     {
>         dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
>         foreach (string item in columns)
>         {                           
>            obj.item = sdr[item];
>         }                        
>         allRows.Add(obj);
>      }                    
> }
> ```

Comment: Try moving the 'dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();' outside the while clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DataTable` does precisely what you're looking for. Instead of doing such common tasks using primitives, use the built-in `DataAdapter` to fetch all values for you from the database in one function call. Even if you're looking for named property members, strongly-typed `DataSets` will solve that for you.

Comment: Question is not about finding a better way to do it. You should have posted this as a comment instead.

Comment: @nikhilvartak : If he suggests a better method which works, or could work, and the OP finds it to do so then this is indeed an answer.